# Restrict the Number of Unique term to be indexed for a Document in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement wherein I need to restrict the number of unique terms to Index for any Document to 1000 in Elastic. Any unique terms beyond 1000 for a particular document should be ignored and not Index during Indexing.
Is there any such setting in the Index template or some other setting for this requirement? This is a legacy requirement.
I was searching for any such settings in Elastic , but could not.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The terms are a list? Provide a document for example.

Comment: Terms are not in list. Basically lets say , If I am indexing the eMail body and the body contains "Sid is the name ". In this case  we have 2 unique terms "Sid" and "name", provided stop words are ignored ("is " and "the").

Comment: Well... it looks like a stop-words filter would solve your problem because it looks like you just want to remove stop words from indexing.